# Understanding view resolution in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to understand how spring mvc generates a markup. For instance, consider the simple controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController{

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

and say, that we're applying UrlBasedViewResolver defined in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` as follows:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/">
    <property name="suffix" value="jsp">
</bean>
```

What [the javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html) of the resolver does is says that we have three methods that return the instance of the [View](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html) interface. 
The first one is

`protected AbstractUrlBasedView buildView(String viewName)`,

the second is

`protected View createView(String viewName, Locale locale)`

and the third is

`protected View loadView(String viewName, Locale locale)`.

As long as the `View` interface has the method `render(Map<String,?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` I'd assume that once the instance of View has been created we call this method to render the markup to the client. But I'm not sure if it actually works that way.

In general, my question is what method takes the a `jsp`-page and return the instance of `View` to be rendered to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In general, my question is what method takes the a jsp-page and return the instance of View to be rendered to the client.

In the case of `UrlBasedViewResolver`, that would be the `createView` method, which for a JSP will return an `InternalResourceView`.

As far as the view resolution framework is concerned, the `ViewResolver` interface is the entry point, and has a method `resolveViewName` which takes the view name ("hello" in your example") and returns a `View` object, then calls `render` on that.

The `buildView`, `createView` and `loadView` methods are all internal specific to the `UrlBasedViewResolver` implementation of `ViewResolver`.